# “unknown variable 'key_buffer_size=256M'” when trying to mysqldump

Tags: mariadb

I have a dedicated 32 GB RAM Centos 7 server. I have very limited knowledge about setting of /etc/my.cnf . I encounter “unknown variable 'key_buffer_size=256M'” during backup and as a result, system create zero size files.

mysqldump: unknown variable 'key_buffer_size=256M'
Database Backup: bor --> bor.sql
building file list ... done
bor.sql

sent 105 bytes  received 46 bytes  302.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00

I couldn't understand what is the problem with key_buffer_size !

Here is the content of my "my.cnf":

```
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

key_buffer_size = 256M
query_cache_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 128M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6500M
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 32M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
max_connections = 250
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
join_buffer_size = 8M
binlog_cache_size = 1M
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: # mysql --version  command gives : mysql: unknown variable 'key_buffer_size=256M'  error.  When I check from Phpmyadmin, it is Server version: 10.1.34-MariaDB - MariaDB Server

Comment: ok you are on mariadb then, not mysql

Comment: The config file(s) are shared for most mysql programs, and `[group]`-indicators are used to specify which programs those options belong to. You should use those and/or modify the files in `/etc/my.cnf.d`, so that `mysqldump` does not think that those options are for `mysqldump` while they are actually intended for the server.

Answer (score 8):

Just before `key_buffer_size = 256M`, add a line:

```
[mysqld]
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your MySQL my.cnf
[mysqldump]
Here you do not add your own
key_buffer_size=256M
You can cancel this parameter